# "Remember those times that" or "remember those times when"

Tags: word-choice, writing-style, when, that-it

I have seen that in certain places the phrase "remember those times that" is used, when I actually find it more natural to say "remember those times when".

Since I am not a native English speaker I was wondering which is more appropriate.

For instance:

- "Remember those times that I met Bob" vs "Remember those times when I
  met Bob".
- "I remember those times that I pretended that I was looking
  around but I was actually [...]"
- "I remember those times that I would
  think about [...]"

I found a case in which it sounded more natural to use that: "remember those times that won't come back again", but this is not the same type of sentence.

What do you think? Are these two forms interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely use when for all of them.